# How to concatenate an auto increment value before inserting into database in laravel

Tags: laravel, concatenation

In my table I have a field that needs to be the same value as the id field which is auto increment and then the value is concatenated with certain strings.

How do I do this in store function of my controller?

I'm thinking of doing update right after insertion but I don't know how to get the inserted id, and that might be a problem if two or more users doing the same insertion into database at the same time.

Thanks

UPDATE:
in my store controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $kartukeluarga = new kartukeluarga();
    $kartukeluarga->nomorkk = $request->input("nomorkk");
    $kartukeluarga->kepalakeluarga = $request->input("kepalakeluarga");
    $kartukeluarga->alamat = $request->input("alamat");

    $kartukeluarga->save();

    return redirect()->route('kk.index')->with('message', 'Item created successfully.');
}
```

the new field I want to add is 'rekamMedik' which doesn't need an input form but automatically concatenate the id and this string "kk-value of the id"

Comment: Can you add some code of how you store the data in your controller?

Comment: @TheFallen I have updated my question and put the code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save details and then update that column.

If you have model `Test`.

```
$test = new Test();
$test->column_1 = "abc";
$test->column_2 = "def";
$test->column_x = ""; // Set Empty to the column where you will save id later
$test->save();

$test->column_x = "string".$test->id;
$test->save();
```

This might work.

Comment: If you solved your problem then, please close the question by accepting this answer.